# How to set ViewPager with two fragments on the side with middle page filled with views and another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In the picture below you can see the desired layout:

[image]

So, ViewPager has three pages, left and right page are statically filled with two fragments (Fragment 1 and Fragment 2) and the page in the center should have a layout that has toolbar on top, bottom toolbar on bottom and fragment in between which can be changed dynamically.

As far as I can see, there are two ways that this can be done.

1. Do some magic with the center page that will have both toolbars and set dynamically Fragment0
2. Each fragment that should go to page in the center should have those toolbars and have the same way of handling events from them, i.e. subclass on `AbstractCenterFragment`, which contains everything needed to implement this layout and behaviour.

Even if it would be easier to implement solution 2, I don't like it at all, for many reasons. I won't address them here, but if you insist, I can provide them.

As for the solution 1, is there anything that you can suggest to solve this from activity level, since activity with all its components (viewmodel, etc..) should handle this layout?

If I use `FragmentPagerAdapter` for `ViewPager` and create parent fragment in the center page which contains toolbar, bottom toolbar and Fragment0, how will that affect performance?

Do you have any other suggestion as using some other type of `PagerAdapter` that will be suffice to handle behavior of given layout?

Thanks!

PS if you give -1 to this question, please, be polite enough to explain why you gave it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made hybrid solution between `FragmentViewPagerAdapter` and usual implementation of `ViewPagerAdapter` with given layout.

Here it is:

```
abstract class NoMiddleFragmentPagerAdapter(private val mFragmentManager: FragmentManager) : PagerAdapter() {
    private var mCurTransaction: FragmentTransaction? = null
    private var mCurrentPrimaryItem: Fragment? = null

    abstract fun getLeftItem(): Fragment

    abstract fun getRightItem(): Fragment

    @Throws(IllegalStateException::class)
    override fun startUpdate(container: ViewGroup) {
        if (container.id == View.NO_ID) {
            throw IllegalStateException( "ViewPager with adapter $this requires a view id.")
        }
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any = if (position == MIDDLE) instantiateCentralArea(container, position) else instantiateFragment(container, position)

    private fun instantiateFragment(container: ViewGroup, position: Int) : Fragment {
        if (mCurTransaction == null) {
            mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        }

        val itemId = getItemId(position)

        // Do we already have this fragment?
        val name = makeFragmentName(container.id, itemId)
        var fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name)
        if (fragment != null) {
            mCurTransaction!!.attach(fragment)
        } else {
            fragment = if (position == LEFT) getLeftItem() else getRightItem()
            mCurTransaction!!.add(
                container.id, fragment,
                makeFragmentName(container.id, itemId)
            )
        }
        if (fragment !== mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
            fragment.setMenuVisibility(false)
            fragment.userVisibleHint = false
        }

        return fragment
    }

    abstract fun instantiateCentralArea(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any

    override fun getCount(): Int = 3

    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) = if (position == MIDDLE) destroyMiddlePart(container, `object`) else destroyFragment(container, position, `object`)

    private fun destroyFragment(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, any: Any) {
        if (mCurTransaction == null) {
            mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        }
        mCurTransaction!!.detach(any as Fragment)
    }

    private fun destroyMiddlePart(container: ViewGroup, `object`: Any) = container.removeView(`object` as View)

    override fun setPrimaryItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, o: Any) {
        if (o !is Fragment) {
            super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, o)
            return
        }
        if (o !== mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
            if (mCurrentPrimaryItem != null) {
                mCurrentPrimaryItem!!.setMenuVisibility(false)
                mCurrentPrimaryItem!!.userVisibleHint = false
            }
            o.setMenuVisibility(true)
            o.userVisibleHint = true
            mCurrentPrimaryItem = o
        }
    }

    override fun finishUpdate(container: ViewGroup) {
        if (mCurTransaction != null) {
            mCurTransaction!!.commitNowAllowingStateLoss()
            mCurTransaction = null
        }
    }

    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, any: Any): Boolean {
        return when (any) {
            is Fragment -> any.view == view
            is View -> view === any
            else -> false
        }
    }

    override fun saveState(): Parcelable? {
        return null
    }

    override fun restoreState(state: Parcelable?, loader: ClassLoader?) {}

    fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val LEFT = 0
        private const val MIDDLE = 1
        private const val RIGHT = 2

        private fun makeFragmentName(viewId: Int, id: Long): String {
            return "android:switcher:$viewId:$id"
        }
    }
}
```

When implementing this adapter in Activity I created following class:

```
private class HomePageAdapter(private val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater, fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : NoMiddleFragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

        override fun getLeftItem(): Fragment = LeftFragment()

        override fun getRightItem(): Fragment = RightFragment()

        override fun instantiateCentralArea(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_content_area, container, false)
            container.addView(view)
            return view
        }
    }
```